# Accessing /admin/content returns "Page not found"

Tags: views, 9

The stock Content view in a Drupal 9 install is returning a 404 when accessing /admin/content.

We added two contextual filters to this View that are ignored if you are an Admin (passes "all" value).

If you navigate to /admin/content/node, you get the View. But admin/content is a 404, and other sites we have work fine (no filters on the View). I see someone changed the path in the View, but changing it back causes it to ping pong between 404 and the View. Is there something else that could cause this?

[image]

Comment: Once it's been customized by adding filters and changing the path, it's not really the "stock" content view.  Returning a 404 instead of access denied is an option buried in the contextual filter settings; check to see if that's set.

Comment: Its a default value that passes 'all' if nothing was found. In fact, the arguments don't trigger xdebug on the admin/content path. So something else must be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out - I needed to set 'skip default argument when constructing View URL' on both filters. Now it works.